# how to find a group multiple times

Tags: regex

I have a list like this:

```
points = ( (41,69) (39,69)  ) ,
points = ( (41,73) (39,73) (39,71)  ) ,
points = ( (9,15) (0,15)  ) ,
points = ( (15,15) (9,15)  ) ,
points = ( (15,22) (9,22) (9,15)  ) ,
```

My goal is to get the tuples of each line in separate groups.
So for the first line, i want to get two groups with `(41,69)` and `(39,69)` and for the second line I want to get three groups with `(41,73)`, `(39,73)` and `(39,71)`

I tried this regex:

```
points = \( ((\(\d+,\d+\)) )+ \)
```

But it returns only the last tuple, for example for the first line `(39,69)` and `(39,69)`, for the second line `(39,71)` and `(39,71)` (also two groups, not three as I would expect).

Comment: Which regex engine are you using? As for the reason why this happens: If a repeated group matches several times, the newer matches will overwrite the older ones.

Comment: Another question: Is it necessary for the regex to check that your tuples are surrounded by another set of parentheses? If not, you could simply check for `\(\d+,\d+\)` and be done with it...

Comment: Variable number of capturing group is not good way to go. Different engines might number them differently. Eg. `(\w\w\w)+` in `abcdef` will match `abc` and `def`, but what will be first capturing group? Might be either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this. It will give you every tuple once. It is simple, if you dont need the context it is in.

```
\([^\(\)]*\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/I294M6/1

Comment: That's it! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Variable number of capturing group is not good way to go. Different engines might number them differently. Eg. `(\w\w\w)+` in `abcdef` will match `abc` and `def`, but what will be first capturing group? Might be either.

From what I see on [demo](https://regex101.com/r/i1R0pZ/1), it usually is `def` but I wouldn't rely on that.

Captured groups should be written explicitly, which doesn't fit you requirement.

Anyway, I wouldn't use such construct and use single tuple matches and iterate over matches, rather than over capturing groups. I recommend pattern suggested in Predicate answer:
`\([^()]*\)`

Explanation:
`\(` `/)` - matches `(` and `)` literally
`[^()]` - matches anything except `(` and `)`, no need to escape them in character class